# Can I refer the SERVICE ACTIVITY (from service pallet) from my SOAPREQUESTREPLY activity in TIBCO

Tags: tibco, businessworks

I just wanted to know whether I will be able to refer the SERVICE ACTIVITY (from service pallet) from my SOAPREQUESTREPLY activity. Because

1. Using my SOAPREQUESTREPLY activity if I refer a service pallet I was not able to get the transport details and soap action for the activity whereas this works fine if I refer the concrete WSDL
2. In my understanding only concrete WSDL has the transport details and hence the above scenario.  So does it mean that I will not be able to refer my SERVICE activity from SOAPREQUEST REPLY activity

Answer (score 0):

Until deployed, or loaded on the tester, the Service activity does carry concrete information.

In that sense, no, you cannot refer to your service's transport details through a SoapRequestReply activity.

You can either :

a) Get the concrete wsdl through the [WSDL Source] tab of the Service activity by saving it as .wsdl (you can omit both the interface and types declaration by unchecking the checkboxes if you are only interested in refering to your WebService locally)

or b) Upon deploying/starting in tester use the RetrieveResources activity as described in the tib_bw_palette_reference pdf to expose your wsdl through an HTTP call.

Hope I helped.